# Meteor <Object> has no method 'subscribe'. On the latest meteor update

Tags: javascript, meteor

I keep getting this error even after I've successfully upgraded to the latest meteor.  Can anyone help?

```
W20141002-17:08:01.669(-5)? (STDERR) 
W20141002-17:08:01.841(-5)? (STDERR) /Users/erikbigelow/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.kundj5++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141002-17:08:01.842(-5)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20141002-17:08:01.842(-5)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20141002-17:08:01.843(-5)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'subscribe'
W20141002-17:08:01.843(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/main.js:1:43
W20141002-17:08:01.843(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/main.js:3:3
W20141002-17:08:01.844(-5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/erikbigelow/Sites/scenewith/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141002-17:08:01.844(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141002-17:08:01.845(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/erikbigelow/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.kundj5++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20141002-17:08:01.845(-5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/erikbigelow/Sites/scenewith/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

**This was directly after I removed the autopublish, and added the below**

server/publications.js:

```
Meteor.publish('scenes', function() {
    return Scenes.find();
});
```

main.js

```
Meteor.subscribe('scenes');
```

collections/scenes.js

```
Scenes = new Meteor.Collection('scenes');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the logs it looks like you're trying to call `Meteor.subscribe` on the server, or at least not ONLY on the client.

Your call needs to be either in the client folder, or in a `Meteor.isClient` block, as it's a [client only method](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe), so it won't be attached to the Meteor object on the server.

Comment: UGH!  You're right, it was outside my client folder and I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what meteor version you've been using, but now you define collections as:

```
myCollection = new Mongo.Collection('mycollection');
```